# How does Spring MVC controllers perform method resolution when a form is submitted?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, controller

I have a Spring MVC form in jsp and I am **having trouble getting the controller method invoked**.

Can someone please explain to me the **mechanism whereby Spring MVC performs controller method execution**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3 and annotations (recommended way of implementing controllers), the @RequestMapping(value="exampleMapping.do") specifies the method that will be executed.  Here is an example:

```
@RequestMapping("/exampleMapping.do")
public String anExample(Model model) {
    // do some stuff
    return "someView";
}
```

So in this case, if your form submit target is exampleMapping.do, the method anExample will execute and return someView (which will resolve to your view folder containing a jsp named someView.jsp if you have your view resolver configured correctly).

Comment: Thanks Skel625, Do you assume a `<form:form action="exampleMapping.do" method="get"> ...` in the jsp?